# Does nodyn invoke node.js as another process?

Tags: node.js, nodyn

I am looking for solution to execute JavaScript in JVM, but without invoking another process - I need everything to be exclusively in the JVM process.

One option that seemed promising is nodyn (embedded), but I was unable to figure out if launches another process or not.
The example they give online in their [readme file](https://github.com/nodyn/nodyn/blob/master/README.md) seems to be a process invocation "look alike". Especially suspicious is the -e parameter which is compatible with the nodyn binary as well.

```
NodynConfig config = new NodynConfig( new String[] { "-e", SCRIPT } );
// Create a new Nodyn and run it
Nodyn nodyn = factory.newRuntime(config);
...
int exitCode = nodyn.run();
```

My questions:

1. Does nodyn/dynjs invoke another process or not?
2. Is nodyn jar, for embedding in JVM, dependent on the nodejs binary or nodyn binary?

Answer (score 1):

No, Nodyn does not invoke another process and it does not depend on any particular binary such as nodejs.

Nodyn uses the [DynJS](http://dynjs.org/) ECMAScript runtime underneath which is a pure Java implementation of a "Javascript" interpreter.

Comment: is correct - there is not another process being invoked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple solution just to execute JavaScript on the JVM (and you don't need the Node.js environment/ecosystem), then have a look into the **[Nashorn](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nashorn/)** project in Java 8. It's a complete JS engine embedded in the JVM.

Nodyn is for providing the Node.js API in the JVM. You don't need it to execute pure JavaScript in the JVM. Nashorn is sufficient.